# Checking the solution of a first order pde

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

I need some help with this exercise.

Given the following pde:
 $  \begin{cases}
     u_t + b(u)\cdot u_x=0\\[6pt]
      u(x, 0) = u_0(x)
  \end{cases}
 $

I have to check that its solution is $u(x, t)=u_0(\psi(x,t))$ where $x=b(u_0(\psi(x,t)))\cdot t +\psi(x,t)$.

It should not be difficult, but i'm making a mess with implicit derivation, and getting nowhere. Thanks a lot for any indication.

Comment: Is $\psi$ constant?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: and hence u is constant itself!!

Comment: Ups, sorry. I should have written $\psi(x,t)$. In other way it makes no sense,

Comment: i am running in a circle trying to do it

Comment: Maybe $\psi$ is constant. That would only imply $u$ is constant over each straight line $x=b(u_0(\psi))\cdot t +\psi$

Comment: Finally i did it wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating with repect to $x$ and $t$ we get $$1=b'(u_0(\psi(x,t)))\cdot u'_0(\psi(x,t)\cdot \psi_x(x,t)\cdot t +\psi_x(x,t)
\\ 0=b'(u_0(\psi(x,t)))\cdot u'_0(\psi(x,t)\cdot \psi_t(x,t)\cdot t+b(u_0(\psi(x,t))) +\psi_t(x,t)$$ so we have $\psi_t(x,t)=-b\psi_x(x,t)$ **equation 1**
Moreover,

$$u_x(x, t)=u'_0(\psi(x,t))\cdot \psi_x(x,t)
\\ u_t(x, t)=u'_0(\psi(x,t))\cdot \psi_t(x,t)$$

Then 
$$RHS=u'_0(\psi(x,t))\cdot \psi_t(x,t)+b\cdot u'_0(\psi(x,t))\cdot \psi_x(x,t)
\\=0$$
using equation 1

Comment: I don't see how you get equation 1. Also, in the second equation you wrote, I think a $t$ is missing, multiplying next to $\psi_t$

Comment: Ok, I just saw it! Thanks a lot, Semsem :)

Comment: I cancel $b' \cdot u'$ from the first two equations

Comment: i have revised the equations and think it is now true